# iOS Deep Linking with Auto Login Token in the URL

Tags: ios, swift, jwt, deep-linking, autologin

I am new to deep linking in iOS and I am trying to make sign-in work with a magic link.

The links that the users would receive in their email inbox would be something like this:

https://subdomain.domain.com/?autoLogin=XXXX...XXXX

I want to extract the auto login token and make sure when users click into this link, it takes the user directly to the app.

What path should I put in the `apple-app-site-association` file?

Currently I have `/?autoLogin=` and it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your URL, `?autoLogin=` is a query item and not part of the path.

In your `apple-app-site-association` you should just need to set the path to `/`. The `?` is messing it up since it's used to match any single character in the string.

If you want to have a specific path, you'll have to update your url to something like `https://subdomain.domain.com/autoLogin?token=XXXX...XXXX`, then you could add `/autoLogin` to `apple-app-site-association`.